# How to calculate yearly cumulative return

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table looks like:

```
Date        stock   price
19980102     xxx    1.2
19980103     xxx    1.3
...
19980102     yyy    1.2
19980103     yyy    3.3
```

Where date are stored in int for some reason and update daily. I want to pick out the symbol of stock with + 5% yearly cumulative return in every year, and it this pattern last for the last 19 years. How to do that please?

Example like: if for xxx

```
(price(19981231)-price(19980101))/price(19980101) > 5%
```

then 1998 is the year, then if every year for 19 years is like that, I will pick XXX.

The tricky part is like: the stock only trade in weekdays, so 19980101 might not have data..

Comment: What do you mean by "cumulative return for the last 19 years"?  Please provide the results you want or at least a real explanation of what the calculation is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for the confusion. I mean for the last 19 years, in each year the cumulative return is 5%. Please see my update.

Comment: Do you want the average over the whole 19 years to be at least 5%, which Gordon's answer gives; or for every individual year to have at least 5%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cumulative return of 5% for the last 19 years is 1.05^19 = 2.53.

So, you can just get the oldest result in the period and the newest result and see if the ratio is at least that big:

```
select stock
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by stock order by date) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (order by date) as cnt
      from table t
      where date >= 19980101
     ) t
group by stock
having (sum(case when seqnum = cnt then price end) /
        sum(case when seqnum = 1 then price end)
       ) >= 2.53;
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. I have some update in the post. More intro there.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this will probably be a bit bizarre but bear with me. I have to say that I don't really understand what you mean by "yearly cumulative return"; you seem to be simply checking the price on the first and last days of the year and comparing them -- there's nothing really cumulative about that. First, let's get the prices by the minimum and maximum dates of the year:

```
SELECT stock, TRUNC(date/10000) AS the_year
     , MIN(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date) AS start_price
     , MAX(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY date) AS end_price
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY stock, TRUNC(date/10000)
```

This will get the start price (as of the first weekday of the year, or at least for the lowest value of `date`) and the end price (for the greatest value of `date`).

Now all we need to do is find out the years where the end price was 105% of the start price:

```
SELECT stock, the_year, start_price, end_price
     , ( end_price - start_price ) / start_price AS yield
     , COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY stock ) AS year_cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT stock, TRUNC(date/10000) AS the_year
         , MIN(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date) AS start_price
         , MAX(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY date) AS end_price
      FROM mytable
     GROUP BY stock, TRUNC(date/10000)
) WHERE end_price >= start_price * 1.05
```

Then get the stocks where `year_cnt` is 19:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT stock, the_year, start_price, end_price
         , ( end_price - start_price ) / start_price AS yield
         , COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY stock ) AS year_cnt
      FROM (
        SELECT stock, TRUNC(date/10000) AS the_year
             , MIN(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date) AS start_price
             , MAX(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY date) AS end_price
          FROM mytable
         GROUP BY stock, TRUNC(date/10000)
    ) WHERE end_price >= start_price * 1.05
) WHERE year_cnt = 19;
```